# Convert video to mpg format using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, converters, mpeg

I am using FFMPEG to convert video files to mpg format. Conversion works fine for audio content, but the output has no video content.
This is the parameters I am using:

> ffmpeg.exe -i "*Path to input file*"  -y -s 640x360 -b:v 1024k -vcodec libx264 -r 29.7 -movflags faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p "output.mpg"

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted the question in SuperUser and got [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/920802/452752)

> The .mpg container is for MPEG-1 & MPEG-2 encoding:
>
> If you wish to encode h.264 you should use .mp4.
>
> If you wish create a .mpg file then omit the codec options, ffmpeg
>   will produce MPEG-2.

I had to omit the unnecessary vcodec parameter(which I was using previously to convert to mp4 format) and it works fine now with the following parameters:

> ffmpeg.exe -i "*sourcePath*" -y -s 640x360 -b:v 1024k -r 29.7
>   -movflags faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p "output.mpg"

Answer (score 1):

This question is better suited for superuser.  Also, please include your console output.

That said - what player are you trying to play the resulting video file in? Given a standard input video file, that command would produce a video output with NO audio.  The output.mpg file should be playable in things like FFplay and VLC.

Comment: Hi occvtech, I have posted the question in Superuser. Here is the link:http://superuser.com/questions/920703/convert-video-to-mpg-format-using-ffmpeg

Comment: Also, my output does have AUDIO. Video content is missing